# Apache 403 на определенное имя каталога

Tags: apache, debian, apache2

Ловлю мистическую ошибку какую то...

Создаю в одном из каталогов сайта еще несколько пустых каталогов. Абсолютно одинаковых по правам, под одним пользователем, но имена отличаются на одну букву, содержимое родительского каталога:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В два каталога нормально стучится, в acme-challenge 403... Нужен в итоге как раз таки каталог acme-challenge.

В логах ничего полезного не увидел. Только:

AH01276: Cannot serve directory /usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive, referer: https://***.ru/.well-known/

95.84.157.211 - - [01/Oct/2020:12:08:33 +0300] "**GET** /.well-known/**acme-challeng**/ HTTP/1.1" **200** 753 "https://***.ru/.well-known/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 YaBrowser/20.9.0.933 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"

95.84.157.211 - - [01/Oct/2020:12:13:13 +0300] "**GET** /.well-known/**acme-challenge**/ HTTP/1.1" **403** 585 "https://***.ru/.well-known/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 YaBrowser/20.9.0.933 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36"

Сервер: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина была в конфиге летенкрипта:

```
Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge/ /usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt/
<Directory "/usr/local/mgr5/www/letsencrypt/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
</Directory>
```